# Security risk in netty-all-4.1.58.Final.jar used by Cassandra

Tags: security, cassandra

It seems Cassandra has been using netty-all.4.1.58.Final, which give high security risk in nexus scan (sonatype-2021-0789, CVSS score 8.4). Do we have a fix for this?

Thanks,
Yingjie

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! A friendly reminder that this site is for getting help with coding, algorithm, or programming language problems so I voted to have your post moved to [DBA Stack Exchange](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=cassandra). For future reference, you should post DB admin/ops questions on https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=cassandra. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

The issues with Netty has already been identified, assessed as "not applicable", and added to the [suppression list](https://github.com/apache/cassandra/blob/cassandra-4.0/.build/dependency-check-suppressions.xml#L74-L84) ([CASSANDRA-17368](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-17368)).

In any case, the Netty upgrade to a newer version is already in progress ([CASSANDRA-17392](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-17392), [CASSANDRA-17992](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-17992)), particularly since it is required for supporting Java 17 LTS in the next major release ([CASSANDRA-16895](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-16895)). Cheers!